# IndexedDB Reference Error: db behaving unexpectedly

Tags: indexeddb

Here is the pseudo code of my programme:

```
for(var res in response.data){
        alert("In required function!");
        var request = db.transaction(["movies"],"readwrite").objectStore("movies").add({id:res,movie_title:JSON.stringify(response.data[res]["movie_title"])});
        request.onsuccess = function(event){
                                // alert("Data "+response.data[res]+" entered!!");
        }
        request.onerror = function(event){
            // alert("Unable to add!");
        }
}
```

The problem is that if I remove the `alert("In required function!");` line, It does not show any error.
Can anyone explain the reason behind it?

Answer (score 0):

You are defining a function within a loop. It does not work like you expect. There are ways to properly define functions in loops, but it is far better to just avoid this programming style entirely. Also, note the difference between *defining* and *calling* a function.

Point 2, indexedDB is async. window.alert is as synchronous blocking function. By blocking I mean the browser waits till you click ok. While it is possible to use the two together, I don't recommend it. Use `console.log` instead, which is non-blocking. The browser will not wait each time.

Here is some pseudocode example of another way of programming that avoids the issue:

```
function foo() {
  for(var res in response.data) {
    bar(response.data[res]);
  }
}

function bar(res) {
    console.log("In required function!");
    var request =  ...add(res['movie_title']);
    request.onsuccess = function(event){
      console.log("Data entered!!", res);
    };
    request.onerror = function(event){
      console.log("Unable to add!");
    };

}
```